# MongoDB Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm new to node.js, express and MongoDB, and still learning. The program had a runtime error when I tried some data association in MongoDB models. The reference has been included in the model already but push() method can't recognize it. The models look like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   text: String,
   author: String
});

var Comment = mongoose.model("comments", commentSchema);

module.exports = Comment;
```

and

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var campgroundSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    image: String,
    description: String,
    comments: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Comment"
        }
    ]
});

var Campground = mongoose.model("campgrounds", campgroundSchema);

module.exports = Campground;
```

The part where these two models are needed looks like this:

```
Campground.remove({}, function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        console.log("removed campground!");
        data.forEach(function (seed) {
            Campground.create(seed, function (err, data) {
               if(err){
                   console.log(err);
               } else{
                   console.log("camp created");
                   Comment.create(
                       {
                           text: "nice campsite!",
                           author: "haiderboi"
                       },function (err, comment) {
                            if(err){
                                console.log(err);
                            }else{
                                Campground.comments.push(comment);
                                Campground.save();
                                console.log("comment added");
                            }
                       }
                   );
               }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

It seems like the array is already defined in the Campground model so I can't tell the error. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you must create the `Comment` first and then include these comment objects in seed object then create `Campground` with the same.

Comment: @AZ_ Is there a way to insert the Comment after the Campground object is created?

Comment: where you face the problem in creating the comments first?

Answer (score 0):

Hey i was have problem like this in my project.And it wasn't working because my blogpost schema was like this:

```
var campgroundSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
image: String,
description: String,
comments: [
    {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Comment"
    }
]});
```

And changed it to this:

```
var campgroundSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
image: String,
description: String,
comments: [
    {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,

    }
]});
```

Because up there you're referring ObjectId and you're setting an object inside your code.It's not match.So you should try like this

Comment: The first piece of code should be fine. Check my answer below, that's the problem in terms of my code

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem! 
Instead of doing

```
Campground.comments.push(comment);
```

I should do

```
data.comments.push(comment);
```

since I wanna push the comment to the current Campground object, I should use the object returned by the callback.